# How to sort a dict of dicts by the length of a list inside child dicts

Tags: python

I'm a beginner to Python, and for the sake of learning I looked up some challenges to solve. Here I have a dictionary, containing several dictionaries, each having a list of dicts. My job here is to sort the dictionary, in descending order, based on which child of `somedict` has more elements in the `key` list.

```py
somedict = {
    'a': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, ]
    },
    'b': {
        'key' : [{}, ]
    },
    'c': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {} ]
    },
    'd': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {}, ]
    },
    'e': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {} ]
    },
    'f': {
        'key' : [{}, ]
    },
    'g': {
        'key' : [{}, {} ]
    },
    'h': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {},]
    }

}

sorted_dict = sorted(somedict, key= lambda k: len(k['a']['key']))

print(sorted_dict)
```

While trying to use `sorted()`, I get:

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to sort the keys as a list, and from that sorted list rebuild the `dict`:

```py
somedict = {
    ...
    # contents elided
}
keys = list(somedict.keys())
sorted_keys = sorted(keys, key= lambda k: len(somedict[k]['key']), reverse=True)

print(sorted_keys)

sorted_dict = {k:somedict[k] for k in sorted_keys}

print(sorted_dict)
```

Output

```
['c', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'a', 'g', 'b', 'f']
{'c': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'd': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'e': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'h': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'a': {'key': [{}, {}]}, 'g': {'key': [{}, {}]}, 'b': {'key': [{}]}, 'f': {'key': [{}]}}
```

And this can be shortened to one line:

```py
sorted_dict = {k:somedict[k] for k in sorted(somedict, key=lambda k: len(somedict[k]['key']), reverse=True)}
```

Comment: Alternative: `sorted_dict = dict(sorted(somedict.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]['key']), reverse=True))`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here you go:

```
somedict = {
    'a': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, ]
    },
    'b': {
        'key' : [{}, ]
    },
    'c': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {} ]
    },
    'd': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {}, ]
    },
    'e': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {} ]
    },
    'f': {
        'key' : [{}, ]
    },
    'g': {
        'key' : [{}, {} ]
    },
    'h': {
        'key' : [{}, {}, {},]
    }

}

sorted_dict = sorted(somedict, key=lambda k: len(somedict[k]["key"]))

print(sorted_dict)
```

**Comparing to your attempt**

Basically, `sorted` iterates over the incoming iterable (here a `dict`) and the custom `key` parameter gives you the `key` of the dictionary for each element of that dictionary. Here, the key is called `k` as a variable name, so the question is:

"Given the key of the dictionary, how do we get the length of the underlying list?"

In this case, we do that by calling `somedict[k]` first, and then the `key` string. This returns the array. We then simply call `len(...)` on that to get the list length.

For example, for the first element in the dict the key is `a`, so `somedict["a"]` returns the subdict: `{'key' : [{}, {}, ]}`. In this subdict, we then extract the value of the key called, also, `key` - with: `somedict["a"]["key"]` and get `[{}, {}, ]`. Then we take the length with `len([{}, {}, ])` which is 2.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It would be worth explaining how this works rather than just answering with it alone, particularly as OP stated that they're a beginner.

Comment: Great idea @ben, added the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the lambda you are passing for `key` and since you want to sort it in descending order, you need also to add `reverse=True`.

```py
sorted_keys = sorted(somedict, key=lambda k: len(somedict[k]['key']), reverse=True)
print(sorted_keys)

# then you can build the sorted dictionary
sorted_dict = {k:somedict[k] for k in sorted_keys}
print(sorted_dict)
```

Output

```py
['c', 'd', 'e', 'h', 'a', 'g', 'b', 'f']
{'c': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'd': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'e': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'h': {'key': [{}, {}, {}]}, 'a': {'key': [{}, {}]}, 'g': {'key': [{}, {}]}, 'b': {'key': [{}]}, 'f': {'key': [{}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right. Two edits:

- `sorted` needs the keys and the values of the top-level dict. So you need to pass `somedict.items()`. This passes a list of tuples with key, value pairs.
- in the sorting lambda, you the the key, value tuple as parameter. You are interested in the value (2nd tuple item = index 1) and then the ‘key’ of it.

So I think this does the trick:

```
sorted_dict = sorted(somedict.items(), key=lambda kv: len(kv[1]['key']))
```